# Issue with ListAdapter when scrolling

Tags: java, android

My problem is I have ListAdapter with some posts consisting of images and text, height of that cells are dynamical changing according to image heights, when I scroll down images are loading and everything is OK, but when I scroll up Images start to load again and layout is twitching as shown in GIF image

[image: GIF file how it looks]

XML file

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/roundborder"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/top_card_view"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/post_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/speech_bubble"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_location"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/speech_bubble"
                android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:background="@drawable/roundborder_gray"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_delete"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:elevation="2dp"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@id/relLayout2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top_card_view"
            android:background="@color/white"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/whois"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/profile_photo"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/black"
                    app:civ_border_width="0.5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_photo"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    />


            </RelativeLayout>



            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/heartLayout"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@color/white">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_heart_red"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_heart_red"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_heart"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_heart_white"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/heart_click"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/image_likes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/heartLayout"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"/>

        </RelativeLayout>





        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/relLayout3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout2"
            android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/grey"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:id="@+id/image_time_posted"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:id="@+id/image_caption"
                android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>




        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

CODE

```
public class MainfeedListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Photo> {

    public interface OnLoadMoreItemsListener{
        void onLoadMoreItems();
    }
    OnLoadMoreItemsListener mOnLoadMoreItemsListener;

    private static final String TAG = "MainfeedListAdapter";

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mLayoutResource;
    private Context mContext;
    private String currentUsername = "";
    private String photo_uid, user_uid;


    public MainfeedListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<Photo> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mLayoutResource = resource;
        this.mContext = context;

    }

    class ViewHolder{
        CircleImageView mprofileImage;
        String likesString;
        TextView username, timeDetla, caption, location, lastdaynum, likes, comments;
        ImageView image;
        ImageView heartRed, heartWhite, comment;
        Button delete;
        RelativeLayout mRellay, mRellay2, RellayHeart;

        UserAccountSettings settings = new UserAccountSettings();
        User user  = new User();
        StringBuilder users;
        String mLikesString;
        boolean likeByCurrentUser;
        Heart heart;
        GestureDetector detector;
        Photo photo;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(mLayoutResource, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            holder.heartRed = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_heart_red);
            holder.heartWhite = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_heart);
            holder.comment = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.speech_bubble);
            holder.likes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_likes);
            holder.caption = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_caption);
            holder.location = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location);
            holder.timeDetla = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_time_posted);
            holder.mprofileImage = (CircleImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_photo);
            holder.mRellay = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.whois);
            holder.mRellay2 = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.relLayout3);
            holder.RellayHeart = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heart_click);
            holder.heart = new Heart(holder.heartWhite, holder.heartRed);
            holder.photo = getItem(position);
            holder.detector = new GestureDetector(mContext, new GestureListener(holder));
            holder.users = new StringBuilder();
            holder.delete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            holder.mprofileImage.setImageBitmap(null);
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(null);
        }
```

I wanted to already loaded posts to fix their hights, and when I scroll up to them just to load image

Comment: While JavaScript has Java in its name, Java and JavaScript are in no way the same language. Please don't tag with JavaScript when you're using Java.